# Counting the numbers in each row using python

Tags: python, pandas, python-2.7

I have a pandas data frame:

```
a   b   c   d
./. 0/1 ./. 0/1
0/1 1/1 0/0 1/1
0/1 1/1 ./. 1/1
```

I want to know, how can I get the total number of "0" and "1" in each row same as:

```
a   b   c   d   C0  C1
./. 0/1 ./. 0/1 2   2
0/1 1/1 0/0 1/1 3   5
0/1 1/1 ./. 1/1 1   5
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's [`.stack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) the dataframe to reshape, then use [`.str.extractall`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extractall.html) to extract all capture groups in the `regex` pattern as columns, finally use [`.notna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.notna.html) + [`.sum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sum.html) on `level=0` to count the number of `0's` and `1's`:

```
df[['c0', 'c1']] = df.stack().str.extractall(r'(0)|(1)').notna().sum(level=0)
```

---

```
     a    b    c    d  c0  c1
0  ./.  0/1  ./.  0/1   2   2
1  0/1  1/1  0/0  1/1   3   5
2  0/1  1/1  ./.  1/1   1   5
```